# what is ICustomTypeDescriptor and when to use it?

Tags: c#, .net, icustomtypedescriptor

I don't understand what it is and when to use it. MSDN didn't help me.
MSDN states that ICustomTypeDescriptor Provides an interface that supplies dynamic custom type information for an object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of resources available that show different use cases for the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface, but in short, the typical use case is to provide custom type description outside of what the standard `TypeDescriptor` provides. The interface is rarely implemented without needing to return custom member descriptors such as a custom `PropertyDescriptor`.

The [Type Descriptor Overview from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx) is a good resource which might help further clarify purpose and usage.

Comment: Here is an example of usage: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/04/26/binding-to-dynamic-properties-with-icustomtypeprovider-silverlight-5-beta.aspx

Comment: Look like you get confuse with ICustomTypeDescriptor and ICustomeTypeProvider in the previous example.

Comment: This helped me to understand it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In MVVM you are supposed to create your ViewModels as plain C# classes exposing properties that can be bound to controls and possibly implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for issuing notifications when you change values of your properties so that the bound controls can take notice. WPF will use reflection to discover the properties of your ViewModel classes.

However, it is conceivable that you might not want WPF to use reflection for discovering properties on your objects. It is conceivable that your ViewModel might not even implement C# properties and instead it might expose named values using some other mechanism. For example, you might build a general-purpose ViewModel which dcontains an `IDictionary<string,object>` populated with named values. If `ICustomTypeDescriptor` did not exist, you would not be able to do this. `ICustomTypeDescriptor` tells WPF to refrain from using reflection to discover the properties of your ViewModel, and instead to discover them by invoking methods of your `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface.

Further reading can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/april/net-matters-icustomtypedescriptor-part-1