# TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() always returns the same PropertyDescriptorCollection reference. Causing parallel processing problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection, parallel-processing, contention

**Preface:** I'm working on moving a library over to process data in parallel, and there is 85%+ contention between threads on `PropertyDescriptor.GetValue()`, making the parallel processing on multiple cores the same and sometimes worse than processing on a single core.

**Problem:**

When `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Type)` is called it seems to be returning the same references to the same `PropertyDescriptorCollection`, which has the same references to all the same `PropertyDescriptor` objects. This is problematic because I need new sets of `PropertyDescriptor` for each thread. Sharing the same resources causes the threads to constantly block each other.

**Concurrency Profiling Output:**
[image]

**Rough Example:**

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var class1 = new ExampleClass();
        var class2 = new ExampleClass();

        var test1 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(ExampleClass));
        var test2 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(ExampleClass));
        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(test1, test2));
        int i = 0;
        foreach(PropertyDescriptor item in test1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(test1[i], test2[i]));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

In this case, each [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx) will return true. Showing that they both are referring to the same objects, and are not distinct. This causes serious performance problems when multiple threads are calling `GetValue()` on the same `PropertyDescriptor` object.

How can I get brand new `PropertyDescriptor` objects for each objects property?

---

**Note:** The same problem occurres with `PropertyInfo` retrieved via `myType.GetProperties()`. The `PropertyInfo`s it returns reference the same objects, so even that is performing caching.

---

**Additional Information/Findings:**

- The MethodInfo for the the properties getters is also cached inside of `PropertyInfo`. So getting and invoking the method is not parallelizable since it will rely on the same MethodInfo instance for all threads.
- The process that `PropertyDescriptor` (`ReflectPropertyDescriptor`) goes through during `GetValue()` uses `Type.GetProperty()` (`RunTimeType.GetProperty()`) which uses a property info cache to return the results.

  - This means `PropertyDescriptor` and `PropertyInfo` seem to use the same shared cache for returning property info instances which they both use for accessing the properties getter method (which is also cached).

**TL;DR:** It's cache all the way down.

Comment: @mjwills Through the Concurrency Profiler in vs2017. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: @mjwills I have a problem set broken down into say 4 parts. Each of these is processed on a different thread. They all return, the results are grouped together, and returned as a whole. During processing each thread uses `PropertyDescriptor`s for the supplied objects to retrieve values via reflection. The problem is that the `PropertyDescriptor`s are not unique, so they can only retrieve one value at a time, causing other threads to wait for the current thread to finish with the `PropertyDescriptor` before retrieving their values.

Comment: `GetValue()` is a method of the `PropertyDescriptor`, which is built into the framework. The type can be any class.

Comment: Cool, so I will assume that is `System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor` then (since `PropertyDescriptor` is abstract).

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: And you have to use PropertyDescriptor specifically? Regular reflection will not suffice?

Comment: @Evk Yes, I need to be able to retrieve properties that have been created at runtime. It's my understanding that only `PropertyDescriptor`s provide that.

Comment: Of course they are the same, they should be (logically) immutable. How exactly does this lead to a problem?  This has XY written all over it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Here is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx) on the TypeDescriptor. It overrides reflection information. Here is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640959/what-is-icustomtypedescriptor-and-when-to-use-it) related to it Can you explain what is `XY`' about this?

Comment: @HenkHolterman As OP said, this is a performance issue caused by the contention inside of `ReflectedPropertyDescriptor.GetValue`. To be more precise, I think it's probably that lock: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeDescriptor.cs,1304    I see now way around here by using TypeDescriptor. Most of thoses APIs are public, so maybe you can try calling `GetAssociation` outside of the threads then fetch the value yourself

Comment: In the end, if you look closely at the code of `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue`, what it does is fetch an object using `GetInvocationTarget`, then uses reflection on it. That's something you can do yourself

Comment: @KevinGosse Close (on your first comment). I call `TypeDescriptor` once per thread, and then use the values it returns thereafter. `TypeDescriptor` seems to cache the providers or descriptors instead of creating new ones for the sake of performance. As you probably understand, this means I'll always be referring to the same objects to matter how many times I get the PropertyDescriptors from it. Which means I might be trying to call `GetValue()` from a dozen threads on the same shared resource.

Comment: I didn't think of replicating the `GetValue()` behavior, vs retrieving distinct `PropertyDescriptor`s. I'll see if I make progress there. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18450/HyperDescriptor-Accelerated-dynamic-property-acces ?

Comment: I tried this with `PropertyInfo` instead, and it has the same problem, where subsequent calls to `type.GetProperties()` return references to the same objects. @Evk Thanks, I would like to have this rely solely on the standard library, however, using a 3rd party dependency is not out of the question if I can't solve this.